# How do I dial phone numbers with extensions with Google Now?

Tags: google-now, accessibility

I am helping my visually impaired brother setting up his Samsung S7 with voice commands. Google Now works pretty well for dialing, it can both dial stored contacts and new numbers by dictating the phone number.

However, often when dialing public services, you need to make a multiple choice afterwards (ie. they use extensions).

Is that possible somehow with voice commands?